# How to prepare training data (remove boundary values)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Have we numpy function or pandas function which make somthinfg like that:

For me, boundary values are the farthest values from the regression line.
That means for me:
the farthest from the line over the line and the farthest from the line under the line.

If I will have  data:

```
l1 = [0,1,4,3,4,3]
df =  pd.DataFrame(l1)
```

It looks like that:

```
   0
0  1
1  4
2  3
3  4
4  3
```

How to find data from index 1 and index 4.
I need to recognize from python script and remove them. I know how to remove but i do not know how to find.

What I want to do:

First I am going to calculate linear regression, next I am going to remove outsider values and next  i am going to recalculate linear regression one more time without the farthest values.

Answer (score 1):

To remove outliers, you can use `Series.quantile`:

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2022)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.normal(5, 2, size=50)})
df.plot.hist(bins=25)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now filter out your dataframe:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['A'].between(*df['A'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]).values)]
df1.plot.hist(bins=10)
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Corrallien for answer, but my data will be closer to linear function, not random and I thing i will have few or over a dozen measurements. There is something like  Least Squares Method and I need remove  something what have highest value square of the errors for measure point. Higher value over the line and higher value under line.